# Contenteditable "new line" <div> instead of <br>

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

First sorry for my bad english, 
i'am trying to creat a text - editor, it's work correctly on google chrome but on MozillaSo the problem is with line break,I have a `contenteditable` element, and whenever I type some stuff and hit ENTER it creates a new `<br>` and places the new line text after it . all i want is to get `<div>` after [Return] instead of `<br>` just like Google Chrome 
**For example** 
on chrome

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <div> <span class="simpleText">line 1</span> </div>
    <div> <span class="simpleText">line 2</span> </div>
</div>
```

on firefox

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span class="simpleText">line 1</span> 
    <br>
    <span class="simpleText">line 2</span> 
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: Please provide an example of what code you have so far.

Comment: How can we give you solution without your details explanation or seeing your example code?

Comment: give the sample code

Comment: Sorry this is the first time that i ask question, is it clear now ?

Comment: please help me , you don't need to see example juste creat `<div contenteditable="true">` and click on enter chrome will creat a `<div>` and mozilla will creat a `<br>`,all i want is that mozilla creat `<div>` like chrome instead of `<br>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]').onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // user pressed enter
      document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<div>');
      return false;
    }
};
```